# How do I return my OUTPUT clause in Laravel DB::insert

Tags: php, sql, database, laravel, sqlsrv

I am using Laravel and sqlsrv, connected to SQL Server 2016 and all is working great until I try to use an output clause in my insert query.

Query is something like

```
INSERT INTO TABLE(Columns) OUTPUT INSERTED.MyDesiredReturnColumn VALUES(Value)
```

This is working perfectly in SQL Server, and returning the desired value, but using Laravel's DB::insert functionality it is only returning a 1 (for successful insert)

I have a workaround that I would rather not have right now, using the CreatedOn field to return the most recently created row, but this has potential issues.

UPDATES: The field I am attempting to retrieve is a uniqueidentifier field (guid) that is created in SQL, not from Laravel-side

After attempting @PrathameshPalav's recommendation of using the Eloquent model creation, the values are being inserted correctly into the DB, but it is not returning the uniqueidentifier still.

```
$inserted = MyModel::create($information);
print "inserted id is " . $inserted->MyModelId;
```

This is printing "inserted id is "

Here is my model:

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;    
class MyModel extends Model
{
    //
    protected $table = 'MyModelBase';
    protected $primaryKey = 'MyModelId';
    public $incrementing = false;
    protected $keyType = "string";
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $fillable = ['field1', 'field2', 'etc'];
}
```

Any ideas would be greatly helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way that I solved this was by incorporating an Eloquent model (as pointed out by @PrathameshPalav), then (loosely) following this tutorial https://danielkoch.work/log/laravels-eloquent-guids.html

Specifically this part

```
public static function boot() {
    parent::boot();

    // Hook when a model is created
    static::creating(function ($model) {
        // Select a new ID
        $result = DB::select( DB::raw('Select NewID() NewUUID') );

        $model->{$model->getKeyName()} = $result[0]->NewUUID;
    });
}
```

After that, I added the primary key I had defined to the `$fillable` array and tested, and it works =)

Thank you both for your help!

Answer (score 5):

You can use Eloquent ORM for this purpose:

```
$insertedObject = ModelName::create($input_array);
```

It will return inserted model object in response. Or if you want only inserted record id then use

```
DB::table($tablename)->insertGetId($input_array);
```

Comment: I will attempt the Eloquent process. Thank you.
 
As for the insertGetId, my understanding is that insertGetId only works if it is an auto-incrementing value, not a uniqueidentifier (guid). Am I incorrect?

Comment: @VulgarCoder Yes, you are correct. insertGetId will work only with auto increment value.

Comment: Alright so I created my eloquent model and performed the MyModelName::create, and it was successful. However, accessing the value of the PrimaryGuidId is returning blank still.

Comment: What is the output object ? Was record saved in database?

Comment: Yes the record was saved in the database correctly, and when printing (or dumping) the inserted object it shows me everything that I had passed it, but doesn't include the uniqueidentifier created from the database.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when you use insert it will return a bool. You can use `insertGetId` to get the the id.

> If the table has an auto-incrementing id, use the insertGetId method
>   to insert a record and then retrieve the ID:

```
$data = [....]; // data that will be inserted
$id = DB::table('xxx')->insertGetId($data);
```

More info:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#inserts